# What does the “rocket science” refer to in this question about a startup?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[Typical Y Combinator Interview Questions](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/27/be-concise-the-top-questions-asked-at-a-y-combinator-interview/) says:

> Where is the rocket science here?

The question might be simple for Americans, but I am outside USA, and I haven't found a reliable answer. I need clarification because I plan to translate it into Chinese for knowledge-sharing.

I guess from [posts containing *rocket science*](http://answers.onstartups.com/search?q=%22rocket%20science%22) that it may mean *silver bullet* (a term used in saying "no silver bullet" from a book named *The Mythical Man-Month*).

Can I say that *rocket science* means something over-complicated that still makes people feel like it's magical, although it is a step-by-step science?

Note: one commenter has pointed out that "silver bullet" is not "a complicated implementation". so my guess is misleading.

Comment: It just means there's nothing complicated about it. Or in the words of George Bush, it's not exactly "rocket surgery".

Comment: @ PIM Geek: In case you didn't realise, a *silver bullet* (or [magic bullet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magic%20bullet)) doesn't particularly imply anything *complicated*. Rather the opposite, in fact, since it's usually used in hypothetical contexts where the hoped-for solution would be easily implemented, if it did in fact exist.

Comment: Thanks, if you didn't mention it, I would still keep that misconception in mind...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Back in the 1950s and 1960s, when ballistic missile design was the cutting edge of military technology, and first the 'missile gap' and subsequently the 'space race' commanded national attention, the 'rocket scientist' was a cultural icon in the US.

[image]

(Never mind that the creative imaginations in the missile and moon programs were mostly engineers rather than scientists; to the public they were all 'scientists', heirs to the team which produced the atomic bomb.)

'Rocket science' came to symbolize arcane mathematical and technological understanding.

Rocket science itself has faded into the background these days; but it has left behind the fixed phrase

[image]

meaning "X does not require specialist knowledge; anybody can understand the principles and perform the necessary actions".

"Where's the rocket science?", then, means in this context "What technological or methodological breakthrough have you achieved which will distinguish you in the marketplace from your competitors? What have you got that they ain't got?"

Comment: I cannot imagine a more impressive answer, thanks!

Comment: When I was in the Air Force, a friend of mine told me that when he was working on the jet-assisted take-off units for the B-1 bomber, they ran into some technical problems, and in exasperation he said, "Come on guys, this isn't rocket science!" One of his co-workers replied, "Well actually, it is."

Comment: "Rocket science"? psssh. It's not Brain Surgery (ref: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THNPmhBl-8I)

Comment: @Jay My late father-in-law (who was the guy responsible for getting the astronauts down safely into the water) would have said "No it isn't. It's rocket **engineering**, which is just as hard and also has to work."

Comment: Wahahaha ...I watched it, @Matt you are really a humorist. [Rocket Scientist said that Brain Surgery is NOT EXACTLY "Rocket Science."]

Comment: In this context, "rocket science," "nuclear physics," and "brain surgery" are more or less synonymous.

Comment: @Tom: Spot on. Really, any complex field that might (a) intimidate the layman, and (b) require a rather extensive education to master would suffice. We've named some of the common ones here, but there's no reason someone couldn't use, say "quantum mechanics" or "differential equations" or even ["it's not like making a soufflé."](http://boeltersuperstore.com/cooking-basics/marinating-101/)

Comment: @J.R. The idea would be the same if you substituted other complex fields, but it would no longer be a common idiom. "It's not rocket science" and "It's not brain surgery" are idioms. "It's not gourmet cooking" would probably be understood, but as it's not a phrase that's routinely used, a reader would have to stop and think about it.

Comment: @Jay: I agree 100%.  Thanks for pointing that out. I wouldn't recommend changing the idiom in business correspondence; that's just inviting confusion. However, in casual, friend-to-friend conversations, I've been known to alter an idiom every now and then, when I think it might sound fresh instead of trite.

Comment: @J.R. True. Breaking the pattern on an idiom is not necessarily bad or wrong. It grabs the readers attention. That is bad if you are using the idiom to make a point, and now you are distracting from that point by calling attention to the idiom itself. It is good if you want to add freshness to the use of the idiom, or if in fact your goal is to call attention to the idiom. Now I think I want to write a science fiction story where a character says, "Hey, this isn't warp drive engineering ..."